# I am getting an AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'xpath' in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am newbie for scrapy and I am using ***Scrapy 0.14.4***. I just want to print title and link as per following example.

Here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class XxxSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "xxx"
    allow_domains = ["xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    start_urls = ["http://xxx.xxx.com/jobs/"]


    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@id='job_listings']/a"):
            title = sel.xpath('./text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('./@href').extract()
            print title, link
```

What is missing in this?

Comment: Why are you using such an old scrapy version?

Comment: I want just learn basic and I think there is missing a module to import for xpath.

Comment: Nope. The problem is that you are using an old version.

Comment: Really, unless there's a reason you can't, I'd *really* recommend updating Scrapy.  You're using software that's over 3 year old. You're going to keep encountering these types of problem if you try and base your code/learning off new content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an old version of Scrapy where selectors were not included in the response objects. To verify this look at the relevant documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/request-response.html

To solve your problem wrap the response into a selector and then you can use the `xpath` function on the selector:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector 
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    for sel in hxs.select("//div[@id='job_listings']/a"):
```

Comment: I am getting an error: ImportError: cannot import name HtmlXpathSelector

Comment: Well, there was a typo -- I fixed the import in the answer.

Comment: I am getting the error:

AttributeError: 'HtmlXPathSelector' object has no attribute 'xpath'

 hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

 for sel in hxs.xpath("//div[@id='job_listings']/a"):

            title = sel.xpath('./text()').extract()

            link = sel.xpath('./@href').extract()

            print title, link~

Comment: Again, to much copy-paste. But you should see the documentation for an example.