# Scrapy not showing yield results at the terminal

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

After running/saving my script, as it follows, I tried to see the results in the Terminal without success.

The code is pretty straight forward but I can't seem to find a work around.

```
import scrapy

class TickersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tickers'
    allowed_domains = ['www.seekingalpha.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/on-the-move']

    def parse(self, response):
        articles_all = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/a/text()').getall()
        articles_gainers = response.path('//div[@class="title"]/a[contains(text(), "remarket gainers")]/text()').getall()
    
        yield {
            'articles': articles_all,
            'articles_gainers': articles_gainers
            }
```

I also double checked that I was running at the correct directory.
This is what shows up when I run `scrapy crawl tickers` at the terminal:

```
2020-07-25 16:53:35 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.2.0 started (bot: seekingalpha)
2020-07-25 16:53:35 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-07-25 16:53:35 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-07-25 16:53:35 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'seekingalpha',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'seekingalpha.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['seekingalpha.spiders']}
2020-07-25 16:53:35 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 2cb47f969c26a413
2020-07-25 16:53:35 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://seekingalpha.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-07-25 16:53:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/on-the-move> (referer: None)
2020-07-25 16:53:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://seekingalpha.com/market-news/on-the-move> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 346, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\MICRO\PythonDir\projects\seekingalpha\seekingalpha\spiders\tickers.py", line 11, in parse
    articles_gainers = response.path('//div[@class="title"]/a[contains(text(), "remarket gainers")]').getall()
AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'path'
2020-07-25 16:53:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-07-25 16:53:37 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 511,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 158291,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.987867,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25, 19, 53, 37, 13084),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 25, 19, 53, 36, 25217)}
2020-07-25 16:53:37 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407140/i-am-getting-an-attributeerror-htmlresponse-object-has-no-attribute-xpath-i) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a typo in your code.

```
    articles_gainers = response.path('//div[@class="title"]/a[contains(text(), "remarket gainers")]/text()').getall()
```

It should be `response.xpath()` instead of `response.path()`. That's what the Exception message is telling you:

```
AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'path'
```